# Date Range picker is not working on page load

Tags: jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using date rang picker calendar API https://www.daterangepicker.com/. I am not able to set the date selected by the user on page load in date dange picker .

```
$('.showDate').daterangepicker({  "showDropdowns": true, "startDate": new Date(),minDate:new Date(),  "singleDatePicker": true,  locale: {
              format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
                daysOfWeek: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
            },
            });
```

what i am doing  to set the date  on page load is

```
$('#TravelDetails_StartDate').val(_startDate);
```

but it only changes  the text box value calendar still holds the same value.
Do i need to refresh the calendar .

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of daterangepicker

```
$("#daterange").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(startDate);
$("#daterange").data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(endDate);
```